# How do I perform a MD5 hash of an unsigned byte array in android?

Tags: android, vb.net, kotlin, md5

I am trying to replicate the password validation done by our VB.NET web application in android.

The main issue is that the VB.NET authentication uses unsigned byte arrays and java uses signed byte arrays. I have added a Kotlin class which can use unsigned byte arrays but the MD5 hash function parameter is a signed byte array and my end result is a different hash than is produced by my VB.NET web application.

Kotlin:

```
val unsignedByteArray ="plainText".toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toUByteArray()
val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
md.update(unsignedByteArray.toByteArray())
```

VB.NET

```
Dim hash As HashAlgorithm
hash = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
Dim hashBytes() As Byte = hash.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes)
```

I need to exactly duplicate the hashing process of the VB.NET web application in order to produce the same hash. My issue is MessageDigest.update() only takes a signedbyte array, while the VB.NET version takes an unsigned byte array, and thus produce different values.

Is there a way I can do a MD5 hash on an unsigned byte array in android?

Comment: maybe this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066835/java-sha-1-hash-an-unsigned-byte/9067096

Comment: There are no unsigned variables in Java.  But it shouldn't matter, because there's no difference in the binary implementation of a singed vs unsigned number-  just the interpretation.  Are you sure that they're both using the same hashing algorithm?  I believe there are variations on md5